# The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using:

- Firefox 56.0.1
- Selenium 3.6.0
- Windows 10 home edition
- Gecko Driver 0.19.0

The error message is

> The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one
>   module: client.combined, net.bytebuddy"

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Something must have went wrong with attaching the screenshot. It's not there.

Comment: Hi Evertone - I added a scren shot to demonstrate the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 44):

This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

**Solution**:

1. Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath".
2. Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars.
3. Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath".

Comment: Thank you very much after wasting 2 days your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are adding `.jar` files to your **Modulepath** instead of **Classpath**.

Go to

- **Project** → **BuildPath** → **Config BuildPath**
- click **Remove Jars from Modulepath**
- then click on **classpath** → **Add external selenium jar files**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add all the required jar files inside classpath instead of module path. The same issue was also occurred with me but after adding the jars to classpath it got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Selenium, but it looks like you have two modules that contain the exact same package name inside of them:

- client.combined
- net.bytebuddy

So when you say e.g. `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` Eclipse doesn't know if you want to use that package from `client.combined` or from `net.bytebuddy`.

You need to either add a prefix in that import statement that will specify whether you're importing package `org.openqa.selenium` from `client.combined` or from `net.bytebuddy`.

You can possibly do this by just doing:

- `import client.combined.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver`
- `import client.combined.org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`

or

- `import net.bytebuddy.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver`
- `import net.bytebuddy.org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`

---

You can also try removing either of the packages (`client.combined` or `net.bytebuddy`) from your project

Answer (score 2):

Add required JAR in class path instead of module path. Also delete unnecessary JARs which might have reference to the mentioned package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and removing the reference to one of the jar files solved the issue. 
Remove the reference to one of the jar files that you added in java build path.
From the screen shot that you added I see you have reference to both
client-combined-3.6.0-sources.jar
and
client-combined-3.7.0.jar
both the packages have the same classes implemented. 
Remove the reference to one and see if that help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used JDK 9 and eclipse oxygen 64-bit version (Selenium 3.9.1). My first thought, it is the JDK 9, but I tested on IntelliJ IDEA JDK 9 and worked without any problem. So I installed the eclipse oxygen 32-bit version with JDK 8 (-no JDK 9 version on 32 bit) and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when same java package code (package name + class name) is available in more than one jar file; for default modules every jar is exposed as Module. Modules essentially can not have same package name exported. This is more of a code cleanup task.