# How to fix a java error that states that a package is accessible to more than one module

Tags: java

I am doing a coding project where I am trying to input a file into java and output information about the file. I have found code online that does this for PDF's. The line "import org.xml.sax.SAXException;" keeps giving me an error and stating that the package org.xml.sax is accessible to more than one module. Can someone help me with this?
Sorry to bother you all, I am a new coder just trying to figure this out.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class PDFTika 
{
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws 
      IOException,TikaException 
   {
      BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new 
      File("/Users/relli/OneDrive/Documents/Asparta/example.pdf"));
      ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

      //parsing the document using PDF parser
      PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser(); 
      pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

      //getting the content of the document
      System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :" + 
      handler.toString());

      //getting metadata of the document
      System.out.println("Metadata of the PDF:");
      String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

      for(String name : metadataNames) 
      {
         System.out.println(name+ " : " + metadata.get(name));
      }
       }
    }
```

Comment: This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

Comment: why do you need this line?

Comment: @Shovon Das, what do you mean by that? I thought I had to add the external jars in the ModulePath in order for TIKA and JNotify to be used in Eclipse. If not, should I remove them? On my partner's computer, we added the external jars to their library and it was not a problem.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I think I need the line to be able to throw a SAXException. When I just commented out the line, I simply ran into problems of using an unhandled exception type

Comment: I can not see where you are catching or throwing this exception, please show the error.  By the way, it is probably being included in multiple places on your class path?

Comment: Check this, It may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834695/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I am happy to show the error. Can I just take a screenshot of my screen and show you. What do you mean when you say that "it is probably being included in multiples places" on my class path? I am sorry for all the questions, I am just new to this

Comment: Yeah a screenshot is OK.  the class path is the external jars that you mentioned before.

Comment: @ShovonDas, I did what you recommended and now the main method is telling me that SAXException is an unhandled exception type

Comment: @ScaryWombat, here is a link to a screenshot. The external jars are now in my class path and the JRE System Library is in my module path. file:///Users/gabrielkatz/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202019-06-18%20at%2010.30.48%20AM.png

Comment: @GabrielKatz - You are new at this aren't you.  Sorry, but I can not access your Desktop PC.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I am! Sorry! The computer is now telling me that the line "pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);" gives me an unhandled exception type. The computer says that the unhandled exception type is a SAXException. I am happy to send a picture if I can figure out how

Comment: @GabrielKatz the only thing that an import statement does is to allow you to use a shorthand name in the code. Nothing more than that. In this case it allows you to say `public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException` instead of fully spelling it out as `public static void main(String[] args) throws org.xml.sax.SAXException`. But the problem is not the import statement itself but the fact you are not declaring the exception in the `throws` statement. When you do, you'll also get the error saying the package is defined in multiple modules (which others have already helped you with).

Answer (score 0):

***Method 1:*** code is a copy of the code provided by Gabriel Katz. I have managed to fix the error just by adding another exception (SAXException) in code.

***Method 2:*** is a simplified version of parsing the PDF content only.

Code Snippet Info:

This code is used to parse PDF data using the ***Apache Tika package***. It will display the pdf content as string and print metadata of PDF file

***Method 1:*** parse PDF and print PDF content and metadata

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFTika {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
        File file = new File("example.pdf");
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);

        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

        //parsing the document using PDF parser
        PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
        pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

        //getting the content of the document
        System.out.println("Contents of the PDF :" + handler.toString());

        //getting metadata of the document
        System.out.println("Metadata of the PDF:");
        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

        for (String name : metadataNames) {
            System.out.println(name + " : " + metadata.get(name));
        }
    }
}
```

***Method 2:*** parse PDF data and print content as a string

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;

public class TikaParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {
        File file = new File("example.pdf");
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        String fileContent = tika.parseToString(inputstream);
        System.out.println(fileContent);
    }
}
```

```
<!--Please add following dependencies for testng-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```