# How do I set up extJWNL in a Java project?

Tags: java, import, wordnet, jwnl

I am trying to determine whether a set of strings, from an English sentence, are all words from the WordNet dictionary. I put the JARs in a folder in my project in eclipse.

I've downloaded the binary release of [extJWNL](http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/) and put the JARs in a folder called lib.

[image: The project hierarchy in Eclipse IDE with the folder called lib which contains the JARs expanded]

I also added these jar files to the class path and the module path using Right Click > Build Path > Configure Build Path:

[image: JAR files under the modulepath and classpath in the properties of the current Java project in Eclipse]

I used the following code to try to import dictionary

`import net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary;`

This error is shown on the import statement

> The package net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary is accessible from more than one module: 
>   <unnamed>, extjwnl

I thought that this error was showing up because it was a package, not a class/type. But adding a new class and trying to change the package doesn't show this new package, namely WORDNET_JARS, just the default package.

Why is this error being returned and what do I need to do to get rid of the error and import the wordnet packages?

**Platforms**

I am using Eclipse IDE, and write all this code in Java. The API I am trying to import is the WordNet API.

### Edit (8/21/2019)

By removing the module path, it gives a new error:

> Only a type can be imported. net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary resolves to a package

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063454/11905620) answer to a similar problem might help.

Comment: This is a similar problem, but then it gives a different error.

Comment: You have added the jar in both ModulePath and ClassPath. External jars should be added to ClassPath. Remove from ModulePath. Also you would need a properties.xml to use JWNL. Try following this tutorial https://blog.roland-speith.de/?p=430

Comment: I would suggest to use a dependency management system like maven or gradle. By doing so you avoid to manally build your classpath. The maven coordinates can be found on the project homepage.

Comment: @bidishamukherjee I am using extJWNL not JWNL, and it has already been downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised it was this easy:

Instead of

> import net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary

I had to do

> import net.sf.extjwnl.dictionary.*

to get all the types. The only other thing that had to be done had already been done where I add the JARs to the class path